# Getting SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2' error while enabling TLS1.2

Tags: linux

I want to enable TLS V1.2 for my application but when I change configuration file I am getting SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2' My OS -> Cent OS 5.5 (Final)
apache version -> Apache/2.2.3 openssl version -> OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008. Does TLS V1.2 needs OpenSSL 1.0* compulsory?

Answer (score 0):

Apache/2.2.3 is not support TLSv1.2

 You need upgrade at least to version Apache 2.2.32 and OpenSSL 1.0.1